# How to recursively get the size of a tree?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

```
class EmptyValue:

   pass

class Tree:

    def __init__(self, root = EmptyValue):
        self.root = root
        self.subtrees = []

    def is_empty():
        self.root = EmptyValue

    def size(self, a = None):

        for subtree in self.subtrees:
            if isinstance(subtree,Tree):
                if subtree.subtrees == []:
                    a+=1
                else:
                    a+=1    
                    return(subtree.size(a))
            else:
                a+=1
        return(a)
```

I'm trying to count the number of items in this tree, however it get's stuck at this case.

a = Tree(5)

b = Tree(6)

b.subtrees = [1,2,3]

a.subtrees = [Tree(11), Tree(5), Tree(3), b, Tree(4), Tree(12)]

print(a.size()) #should print 10, gives 8

I think the loop stops at b and has something to do with the subtrees of b not being trees themselves , any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `def size(self, a=1):` would work just as well; defaulting to `None` is only a best practice for mutable objects, which integers aren't.

Comment: Beyond that, frankly, I'm not sure the logic makes a lot of sense here. Why are you looking into `subtree.subtrees` at all? Wouldn't it make more sense to only look at `self.subtrees`, and rely on recursion for *all* inspection of children?

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this, but wouldn't you only want to use recursion if the subtree in self.subtree was a Tree?

Comment: Of course; nothing I said above conflicts with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `size` definition is more complicated than it needs to be -- and in that complication hides bugs:

```
def size(self, a=1):
    for subtree in self.subtrees:
        if isinstance(subtree,Tree):
            a += subtree.size()
        else:
            a += 1
    return(a)
```

Note in particular that we only have one `return` point -- after **all** subtrees have been evaluated, whereas the old code allowed a `return` to take place at any point in the process, meaning that later children wouldn't be considered.

Comment: What is the difference between returning and just calling the function?

Comment: When a function `return`s, it is finished operating -- it can run no more code. So, if you `return` during the first iteration through your `for` loop, you never get to run any additional/later iterations of that same loop.